# Using a linear function as a routine to determine a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a linear function, i.e., $$F(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha F(x) + \beta F(y)$$

Suppose you are given a routine that returns $F(x)$ given any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. How would you use this routine to determine a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $F(x) = Ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

If we have a standard basis $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ we have a unique $x$ where $$x = \sum_{i}^{n}e_ix_i \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$$ By linearity we have $$F(x) = F(\sum_{i}^{n}e_i x_i) = \sum_{i}^{n}F(e_i)x_i = \sum_{i}^{n}a_i x_i = Ax$$ where $F(e_i) = a_i = A e_i$ determines the $i$-th column of $A$

This course is called foundations of computational math, although the above math is more on the linear algebra spectrum. I am just curious to see whether this approach makes sense and whether anyone has a better idea of what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the matrix as follow:

First specify the basis on each space, say, the standard one on each:
$${\Bbb R}^n={\rm gen}\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$$ and
$${\Bbb R}^m={\rm gen}\{e'_1,e'_2,...,e'_m\}$$
Then, map each $e_i$ to get $Te_i$, but since $Te_i$ lives in ${\Bbb R}^m$ 
hence
$$Te_1=a^1{}_1e'_1+a^2{}_1e'_2+\cdots +a^m{}_1e'_m,$$
$$Te_2=a^1{}_2e'_1+a^2{}_2e'_2+\cdots +a^m{}_2e'_m,$$
$$\cdots$$
$$Te_n=a^1{}_ne'_1+a^2{}_ne'_2+\cdots +a^m{}_ne'_m.$$

So the matrix you are seeking is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
a^1{}_1 & a^1{}_2 &...&a^1{}_n\\
a^2{}_1 & a^2{}_2 &...&a^2{}_n\\
\vdots&&\ddots\\
a^m{}_1 & a^m{}_2 &...&a^m{}_n
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: What is gen$\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$

Comment: strictly speaking is the vector space generated by the set $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$, then, if $x\in {\rm gen}\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ hence $x=x^se_s$